# What is Canonical wire format of a DNS TSIG RR name?

Tags: dns, dnssec

As per RFC 2845 the TSIG RR key name should be in the Canonical wire format. What does canonical wire format exactly mean? I have gone through the RFC 2523 and it states that 
"For purposes of DNS security, the canonical form for an RR is the
   wire format of the RR with domain names (1) fully expanded (no name
   compression via pointers), (2) all domain name letters set to lower
   case, (3) owner name wild cards in master file form (no substitution
   made for *), and (4) the original TTL substituted for the current
   TTL."

For example if the keyname is abc.def.shared.key, will it be "\003abc\003def\006\003key\000" in the canonical wire format ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the missing "shared" is a typo, that is how the name field should look, yes. If you're using a third-party library to convert to wireformat the most important bit is probably to make sure it doesn't do name compression on your TSIG RR when it's added to the outgoing packet. Also don't forget to set the TTL field to the correct (original) value.

Comment: Dybedhl : Thanks for the clarification and shared is indeed a typo. One small correction tough, TSIG RR TTL is always 0. No substitution is needed for TTL field for TSIG RR.